# Can Spiritomb be encountered without a Nintendo Online account?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, nintendo-switch-online, pokemon-crown-tundra

Spiritomb can be caught in the Crown Tundra DLC. It requires you to [speak to 32 trainers online](https://apptrigger.com/2020/10/27/pokemon-sword-shield-spiritomb/). However, I don't have a Nintendo Online account. Given this, is it possible to encounter Spiritomb by speaking to trainers online or by another method (without trading or transferring from Pokemon Home)?

Comment: You could always take advantage of the 7 day free trail. Granite this does require you to put in card information, but you can always turn off auto-renewal before the trial ends

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the question, encountering Spiritomb requires talking to 32 trainers online. You can't encounter Spiritomb without talking to trainers online, which requires a Nintendo Switch Online subscription.

Comment: You _could_  do it by using local network players, theoretically

Comment: I don't think players in local network appear in your game the same way online players do, but I haven't checked.

Comment: I don't know for sure either, but it was proposed on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonSwordAndShield/comments/jhwcvo/any_way_to_get_spiritomb_without_nintendo_online/ga2ooqi)

Comment: The reddit method seems to suggest that it is possible with local players - this seems likely to work although it's based on speculation